# Установка dovecot на CentOs 6

Tags: centos, dovecot

Пытаюсь установить dovecot, делаю все по гайду
https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/dovecot-installation-and-configuration-on-centos/

После выполнения команды:

```
$ sudo yum install dovecot
```

Нужно внести настройки в файл:

```
/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

Но такой папки (dovecot) и соответственно конфигурационного файла в каталоге /etc нет. Что я делаю не так? Мне его вручную создать? 
Цель сделать вот это скрипт рабочим:

```
echo "Установка и конфигурирование Dovecot"
yum -y install dovecot
cp /etc/dovecot/h0uoixdovecot.conf{,.orig}
cat <<'EOF' > /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
listen = *
ssl = no
protocols = pop3 imap
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_access_groups = vmail
default_login_user = vmail
first_valid_uid = 2222
first_valid_gid = 2222
#mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n

passdb {
    driver = passwd-file
    args = scheme=SHA1 /etc/dovecot/passwd
}
userdb {
    driver = static
    args = uid=2222 gid=2222 home=/var/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
}
service auth {
    unix_listener auth-client {
        group = postfix
        mode = 0660
        user = postfix
    }
    user = root
}
service imap-login {
  process_min_avail = 1
  user = vmail
}
EOF
rm /etc/dovecot/passwd
touch /etc/dovecot/passwd
rm /tmp/vmp
mailpass=`echo -e $mps`
doveadm pw -p $mailpass -s sha1 | cut -d '}' -f2 > /tmp/vmp
```

там ещё какой-то файл должны быть, в этом каталоге, например `h0uoixdovecot.conf`. Почему их там нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отбой тревоги, судя по всему были какие-то проблемы с моим ftp клиентом, просто через консоль перешел в каталог etc и увидел, что все папки на месте и конфигурационный файл тоже